# Graphing from saved values in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble getting my code to work for this equation:

```
hb = 0.5 + (qr*t) - [definite integral between t1 and t2 of (qdt)]
```

I'm only getting one value for `hb`, how would I save the values? (To get a graph of head against time.)

Update: I have added an index to my for loop to store values but now I can't graph the result. Not sure why?

```
% Fluids Project: Power Generation code
clear all;
clc;

R = 15;
Qr = 61.17;
A = 2.47e05;
Tp = 12;
Q = 100;
g = 9.81;
p = 1000;




q = (Q)/((A*R)/(Tp));
qr = (Qr)/((A*R)/(Tp));

t1 = 0.25;
t2 = 0.75;

ii=0;
for t=0:0.01:1
    ii=ii+1;
    tide_height = 0.5*cos(2*pi*t);
    hb= 0.5 + qr*t;

    if t>t1 && t<t2
        hb = hb -  (q*t);
    end

H(ii) = hb - tide_height;

end



plot (t,H);
grid on;
title ('Head Available');
xlabel ('Time');
ylabel ('Head');
```

Comment: You can't get an infinite loop with that `for` loop. This functions just fine on my machine.

Comment: Sorry "excaza" i copy and pasted the wrong question, that was a previous mistake that i fixed

Comment: You need to use an iterator for `hb`. [MATLAB's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html) contains many examples for storing data in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why is because you defined `t` to be a loop variable.  `t` will only be a single value.  You are expecting `t` to be an array at the very end.

There are two ways you can solve this.

## Method #1 - Change your `plot` call

Change your `plot` call so that it is an array to be of the same time space as the output `H`:

```
plot(0:0.01:1, H);
```

## Method #2 - Declare a time array and change your `for` loop

You can declare an array `t` to be of the time steps you desire, then modify your `for` loop so you're accessing each element in `t` correctly:

Before the loop, do this:

```
t = 0:0.01:1;
```

Next, in the `for` loop do:

```
for tt = t
```

`tt` will now be the loop counter variable.  You'll have to change all references of `t` to `tt` though:

```
t = 0:0.01:1; %// Change
for tt = t %// Change
    ii=ii+1;
    tide_height = 0.5*cos(2*pi*tt); %// Change
    hb= 0.5 + qr*tt; %// Change

    if tt>t1 && tt<t2 %// Change
        hb = hb -  (q*tt); %// Change
    end

    H(ii) = hb - tide_height;

end
```

If you decide to do this approach, there's no need to change the way you call `plot` at the end of the code.

---

This should now give you the right graph.... which I get to be:

[image]